# How to find bright green laser dot by using OpenCV?

Tags: android, image, opencv

There was code for detect green bright laser dot in android openCV, but its detect all what ever that green colors, i want only detect bright laser, what ever that i done i had post it.

IF ANY LINK FOR THAT PLEASE LET ME KNOW

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
    Core.inRange(hsv, new Scalar(45,100, 100), new Scalar(75,255,255), 
    lowerRedRange);
    Imgproc.threshold(lowerRedRange, bw, 0, 255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    // dilate canny output to remove potential
    // holes between edge segments
    Imgproc.dilate(bw, bw, new Mat(), new Point(-1, 1), 1);

    // find contours and store them all as a list
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    contourImage = bw.clone();
    Imgproc.findContours(
            contourImage,
            contours,
            hierarchyOutputVector,
            Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,
            Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    );

    // loop over all found contours
    for (MatOfPoint cnt : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f curve = new MatOfPoint2f(cnt.toArray());

        // approximates a polygonal curve with the specified precision
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(
                curve,
                approxCurve,
                0.02 * Imgproc.arcLength(curve, true),
                true
        );

        int numberVertices = (int) approxCurve.total();
        double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(cnt);

        Log.d(TAG, "vertices:" + numberVertices);
        // ignore to small areas
        if (Math.abs(contourArea) < 100
            // || !Imgproc.isContourConvex(
        ) {
            continue;}
        if (numberVertices >= 4 && numberVertices <= 6) {
        }

        else {// circle detection}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your color ranges are not strict enough. In the image below you can see the values I used. The circle around the dot is actually easiest to separate. The dot is harder because it contains very white colors, that is, colors with low saturation. But so does the background, so use the ring instead.
If you want the dot specifically, you can use the inner contour of the ring.

Note: inRange returns a binary mask, so this line in your code does nothing:
`Imgproc.threshold(lowerRedRange, bw, 0, 255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);`

[image]

[image]

**Update**: request for the code in the comments.
The picture with the sliders is a Python script you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator)
Code for the detail picture with the final result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np  
# load image
img = cv2.imread("BPcph.jpg")
# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
# set lower and upper color limits
lower_val = np.array([58,204,219])
upper_val = np.array([101,255,255])
# Threshold the HSV image 
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)
# remove noise
kernel =  np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# find contours in mask
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contours
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),2)
#show image
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks J D for your valuable response, please share some code for that , its really help full for me

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the answer. I use Python, but it should be pretty easy to convert.

Comment: Thanks for your reply J.D, is there a chance you can help me provide this code in android? since i have no knowledge of working on python and i tried but didnt find any converters that could convert python to android. Thanks

Comment: The function names are the same, you already used nearly all the ones I used. If you don't know how to use a function look it up in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/index.html). Replace my code line by line, using the code you made - while looking how it is used. Example: my code has `np.array()`, the same is done in your code with `new Scalar()`.